# How do I count the number of words (text) in an HTML source

Tags: java, html, count

I have some html documents for which I need to return the number of words in the document. This count should only include actual text (so no html tags e.g. html, br, etc).

Any ideas how to do this? Naturally, I would prefer to re-use some code.

Thanks,

Assaf

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Strip out the HTML tags , get the text content , reuse [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org)
- Read file line by line , hold a `Map<String, Integer> wordToCountMap` and read through and operate on the `Map`

Comment: You have missed the (non-trivial) step of actually tokenising the resulting text after stripping HTML

Comment: The first step of converting from html to text was done using the following:
public static int wordCountHtml(String html) {
  // uses http://jsoup.org
  Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
  String text = doc.body().text();
  return wordCount(text);
 }

Now I need to figure out how to count words of text. As mentioned on this post...it is not trivial. Anyone with ideas?

Comment: @Assafn . Once you have stripped out the html, write the plain text to some `File` and read it using `BufferedReader` and `FileInputStream` line by line and process it. I hope  its helpful now

Comment: Working with the text is not the problem. Tokenizing is the problem as we need to break into words and as stated below, that is not trivial.

Comment: well `split(" ")` would do that, and if you need particular words those can be defined using regex you can split them by reg ex

Answer (score 5):

Solution with jsoup

```
private int countWords(String html) throws Exception {
    org.jsoup.nodes.Document dom = Jsoup.parse(html);
    String text = dom.text();

    return text.split(" ").length;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the copy & paste solution! `Jsoup.parse(html).text().split(" ").length` FTW

Answer (score 0):

I would add an extra step to Jigar's answer:

- Parse out the document text using JSoup or Jericho or Dom4j
- Tokenise the resulting text. This depends on your definition of a "word". It is unlikely to be as simple as splitting on white-space. And you'll need to deal with punctuation etc. So take a look at the various Tokeniser's available e.g from the Lucene or Stanford NLP projects. Here are some simple examples you will encounter:

  `"Today I'm going to New York!"` - Is "I'm" one word or two? What about "New York"?

  `"We applied two meta-filters in the analysis"` - Is "meta-filter" one word or two?

And what about badly formatted text, e.g missing of a space at the end of a sentence:

```
"So we went there.And on arrival..."
```

Tokenising is tricky...

- Iterate through your tokens and count them up, e.g using a HashMap.